# Consuming Azure Function in an Express application

Tags: node.js, azure, express

I made an **azure function** that generates suggestions by ChatGPT. I can run the **browser locally**, but I tried to run on the server **side locally (node js)**. It returns the following error:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11413:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:7071
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
    errno: -4078,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '::1',
    port: 7071
  }
}
```

[image]

My azure function:

```
const { app } = require("@azure/functions");
const openai = require("../../lib/openai");

app.http("getChatGPTSuggestion", {
  methods: ["GET"],
  authLevel: "anonymous",
  handler: async (request, context) => {
    const response = await openai.createCompletion({
      model: "text-davinci-003",
      prompt:
        "Write a random text prompt for DALL·E to generate an image, this prompt will be shown to the user, include details such as the genre and what type of painting it should be, options can include: oil painting, watercolor, photo-realistic, 4k, abstract, modern, black and white etc. Do not wrap the answer in quotes.",
      max_tokens: 100,
      temperature: 0.8,
    });

    context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

    const responseText = response.data.choices[0].text;

    return {
      body: responseText,
    };
  },
});
```

[image]

My code in Node JS with Express:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  fetch("http://localhost:7071/api/getChatGPTSuggestion", {
    cache: "no-store",
  })
    .then((data) => data.text())
    .then((get) => res.send(get));
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("El servidor está funcionando en el puerto 8080");
});
```

[image]

I think I need to configure my azure function. But I don't know what exactly it is.

I from LATAM and I new in English sorry.